# How to read float array from postgres via command line

Tags: postgresql, command-line, floating-point, psql

I have a postgres db with a blob column containing a float array. It was written with C# code, using NHibernate. How can I read the numbers with simple tools on command line?

When I use `psql`, for each entry I get a string starting with `\x`, followed 8*n hex digits.
How can I convert that and print the values as decimal numbers, one per line?

Using `pg_dump (credentials) -t table_name --schema-only` I get

```
CREATE TABLE public.my_table_name (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    .. (other columns)
    valuesx bytea,
    valuesy bytea,
);
```

Comment: Can you share the DDL for you table?

Comment: @Mureinik, I ran pg_dump as above and added the output. Is that what you meant?

Comment: how "simple" do you want?  Given that these are encoded in a format that is opaque to the database (and hence standard tools) you're likely going to need some custom code to do the translation.  NHibernate might provide something convenient, but if it doesn't you could define a Postgres function to decode these values into a standard array which normal tools would know about.  I'd probably use [plpython](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython.html) for this as the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) should make this easy.